# How to set Material UI checkbox list checked by default?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to set  all items checked by default when the component first renders.
From docs, there is a property `defaultChecked`, but the setting as a `true` doesn't help.
Also, it doesn't work with `checked` property.
Here is the [demo link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-multiple-select-with-select-all-option-forked-iog8do?file=/src/App.js) and code example

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";
import ListItemIcon from "@mui/material/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import Select from "@mui/material/Select";
import { MenuProps, useStyles, options } from "./utils";

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
  const isAllSelected =
    options.length > 0 && selected.length === options.length;

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    if (value[value.length - 1] === "all") {
      setSelected(selected.length === options.length ? [] : options);
      return;
    }
    setSelected(value);
  };
  console.log("selected", selected);

  return (
    <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
      <InputLabel id="mutiple-select-label">Multiple Select</InputLabel>
      <Select
        labelId="mutiple-select-label"
        multiple
        value={selected}
        onChange={handleChange}
        renderValue={(selected) =>
          !isAllSelected ? selected.join(", ") : "alle"
        }
        MenuProps={MenuProps}
      >
        <MenuItem
          value="all"
          classes={{
            root: isAllSelected ? classes.selectedAll : ""
          }}
        >
          <ListItemIcon>
            <Checkbox
              defaultChecked
              classes={{ indeterminate: classes.indeterminateColor }}
              //checked={isAllSelected}
              // indeterminate={
              //   selected.length > 0 && selected.length < options.length
              // }
            />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText
            classes={{ primary: classes.selectAllText }}
            primary="Select All"
          />
        </MenuItem>
        {options.map((option) => (
          <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <Checkbox
                defaultChecked
                //checked={selected.indexOf(option) > -1}
              />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={option} />
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

https://mui.com/components/checkboxes/

You don't set defaultChecked to anything, you just pass it to the component:

```
<Checkbox defaultChecked />
```

Side note: It might be a good idea to upgrade to v5 of MUI. Looks like you're using the old v4 or earlier packages. (material-ui is the old package naming convention)

https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/

Comment: Hi @Nate, thanks for the answer. I upgraded the mui version to 5 and passed defaultChecked without setting it to true. 
And now it shows all items checked, but what I don't understand, is that it only makes the checkboxes checked, but doesn't update the state array, which is called "selected". The state is still empty.
How can we also have all the items that are checked, also wrap in the state.
Here is the updated link https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-multiple-select-with-select-all-option-forked-iog8do?file=/src/App.js